# How to ensure dates are in correct format for OleDbCommand parameters?

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-access, ado.net

When I execute the code below against an `MDB` database, the data table is empty, however when I run this in a query tool against the database it returns 2 records.

What could be the problem?

Is it an issue with the date format of the parameters (ie. 8/5/13 vs 5/8/13)?

```
Using oDB As OleDbConnection = GetDbConnection()
    Using oCmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * " & _
            " FROM Table1, Table2" & _
            " WHERE (Table1.Date BETWEEN @Date1 AND @Date2) AND (Table1.Id IS NULL) AND (Table2.number = Table1.num) AND (Table1.code1 = Table2.code1) ", oDB)
        oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date1", Date.Today)
        oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date2", Date.Today.AddDays(Me.intDaysAhead))
        oDB.Open()
        dt = New DataTable()
        Using da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(oCmd)
            da.Fill(dt)
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: If the datetime format does not match what database is using those comparisons will not work. Use `DateTime.ToString("FormatString")` to ensure your dt formats are identical. PS: don't tag vb as C#.

Comment: Whats with table3, did you want a cartesian product?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: no, removed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right. I recommend to specify a parameter type [OleDbType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbtype%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
 oCmd.Parameters.Add("@Date1", OleDb.OleDbType.Date).Value = Date.Today
```

Comment: That line does not compile in my Visual Studio 2010 IDE.

Comment: The error message is: `Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment.`

Comment: I the answer is new version of the code. Now it is tested in VS2010. Please don't forget to modify the code for "@Date2" similar way.